# "invoke" the method addEventFilter with an Interface java

Tags: java

how i can use this correctly?

```
EventHandler<KeyEvent> handler = event -> System.out.println("EeventHandler");

    EventType<KeyEvent> event = KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED;

    List<Field> txtFields = Arrays.stream(getClass().getDeclaredFields()).filter(field -> field.getType().isAssignableFrom(TextField.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    txtFields.forEach(field -> {
        try {
            Method m = field.getType().getMethod("addEventFilter", event.getClass(), EventHandler.class);
            m.invoke(field, event, handler);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Get an "IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class" Error on "m.invoke(field, event, handler);", so anything with the EventHandler object is might be wrong?